# Getting percentages out of a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R (a few months experience from online learning and reading) and have no coding experience before this.

I have been using a data set obtained from work (healthcare) for some practice.  I wanted to demonstrate certain patient outcomes over time (by month) in this data set.

I've separated the data by month into a separate data frames that I have stored in a list.  I then narrowed down each data frame within the list to the 3 post-operative outcomes that I want to look at.  All three outcomes are binary (Y or N).

I would like to know if there is anyway I can work out the percentages of "Y" for each of these outcomes by month, and then store this in an object that I can then plot to show the trend over time (by month).

Have I approached this problem completely wrongly?  Should I not have used a list at all?

I managed to get to a point where I have a list of tables of Y's and N's but am now completely clueless as to what to do from there.

```
   list(structure(list(Mobilised_D1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = 
"factor"), 
Catheter_rm_D1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
Diet_D1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = 2:15), 
structure(list(Mobilised_D1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), Catheter_rm_D1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Diet_D1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = 16:31), 
structure(list(Mobilised_D1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    Catheter_rm_D1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    Diet_D1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = 32:42), 
structure(list(Mobilised_D1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), Catheter_rm_D1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Diet_D1 = 
structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = 43:60), 
structure(list(Mobilised_D1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), Catheter_rm_D1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), Diet_D1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 61:74), 
structure(list(Mobilised_D1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), Catheter_rm_D1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Diet_D1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = 75:90))
```

Comment: Can you use `dput` to give us a sample of your data?

Comment: Please use `dput(list_name)` to share your data and also show what output do you expect based on the data shared. See how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I've edited the question, is that what you mean by using dput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each component of the input list, `L`, take the indicated mean arranging that into a multivariate time series with one row per month.  Then plot it on a single panel.  Remove `facet=NULL` if you want each series in a separate panel.

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

series <- zoo( t(sapply(L, function(x) colMeans(x == "Y"))) )
autoplot(series, facet = NULL) + geom_point()
```

(continued after graph)

[image: screenshot]

### Alternative

An alternative is to create a data frame `DF` from `L` along with a `month` vector aggregating by month as shown.  This makes use of the fact that `DF` will have row names consisting of the month followed by a decimal point and a row number from the original component that each input row was was constructed from.

```
DF <- do.call("rbind", setNames(L, seq_along(L)))
month <- as.integer(rownames(DF))
series <- aggregate(zoo(DF == "Y"), month, mean)

autoplot(series, facet = NULL) + geom_point()
```

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you so much.  I have not come across the zoo package before.  This will be really useful for future work.

Comment: I can follow the logic of most of the first method.  The only thing I tried to work out is if I didn't use sapply, e.g. with just one set of data, how would I use colMeans to get the means out of a column containing Y and N values?  I've always just assumed colMeans work only on numbers

Comment: If `x` is a vector of `Y` and `N` then `mean(x == "Y")` is the fraction of `Y` values and if `DF` is a data.frame (or matrix) then `colMeans(DF == "Y")` is a vector,  one element per column, of those fractions.

Comment: Much appreciated again.